# Duplicates in MYSQL based on date and status

Tags: mysql, duplicates, updates

This is my current query to find duplicate phone numbers.

```
SELECT 
    id, cust_num, entry_date 
FROM 
    nums 
GROUP BY 
    cust_num 
HAVING 
    count(*) >= 2 
ORDER BY 
    id 
DESC
```

However, now Im looking to update them all in one go, based on criteria.

I only want to update the newer ones with higher id's than the original.
And only if they have a certain status.

Heres an example, of what I would update based on a list of duplicates pulled from database.

```
 ID |  Num | date    | status
  1    555    Sep-12   NEW    (this row wouldnt update first instance of 555)
  33   555    Oct-12   NEW    (this row would update, duplicate with NEW as status)
  42   333    Dec-12   NEW    (this row wouldn't update first instance of 333)
  5    555    Jan-13   ACTIVE (this row wouldnt update, duplicate but wrong status)
  66   333    Feb-14   NEW    (this row would update, duplicate with NEW as status)
  6    555    Jan-13   NEW    (this row would update, duplicate with NEW as status)
  77   333    Mar 15   ACTIVE (this row wouldnt update, duplicate but wrong status)
```

So the real question is, what query would I use to pull all the duplicates like this, and then update them based on their status.

Comment: dont worry i got you on this one.   gonna go set up a fiddle... stand by

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE nums n SET ... WHERE n.status='NEW' AND (select count(*) from nums where num = n.num and id < n.id and status = 'NEW') > 0;
```

Add in your SET statement for whatever you want to update.

Comment: I dont see how this helps at all.  Maybe im stupid.  Where is the HAVING GROUP BY.  How is it gonna find the duplicates???

Answer (score 0):

Here is the select.  and the link to [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c07d/5)

```
select * from mytable as m where `status` = 'NEW' and exists 
    (select * from mytable as mm where mm.`id` < m.`id` and mm.`num` = m.`num`)
```

**Update status to UPDATED**

```
update mytable as m set m.`status` = 'UPDATED' where `status` = 'NEW' and exists 
(select * from mytable as mm where mm.`id` < m.`id` and mm.`num` = m.`num`)
```